# Prevent Inkscape to make multiple pages PDF for LaTeX

Tags: inkscape, latex

When I generate a PDF from a Drawing using Inkscape 0.92.1 on Ubuntu, it creates a multiple page document which is barely not displayed then in a LaTeX document.

How could I prevent Inkscape to make multiple pages PDF?

Here's the pages layout on the PDF document viewer on Ubuntu (Evince) just to clearly see the problem:

[image: PDF multiple pages output in Evince on Ubuntu]

Comment: Did you forget to post an example image? or example of the PDF?

Comment: I had error yesterday with image upload. It's beeing fixed now.

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. When I export a PDF from Inkscape, I get a single page document.

Comment: What are your page settings for the document? Does your drawing fit on one page in Inkscape?

Comment: Maybe you should add the key element to this question: you export to pdf while selecting `omit text in PDF and create LaTeX file`. And to prevent layers, move all text to the foreground prior exporting, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350175/36296

Comment: it also makes several pages when all the text is on front. And there's still an extra page within the "pdf_tex" file exported that doesn't appear in the pdf where the drawing is. This is clearly a bug for me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the additional page has been fixed, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1417470/comments/45

This will still create multiple layers, which is intended behaviour. If you don't like it, a workaround is to move all text to the top layer, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350175/36296